# SQL Server: loop within a select statement to get n number of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops

I am attempting to write a query that will give me a table with an n+1 number of columns. Rather than just write out each column, changing the n value each time, is there way to loop through it in SQL Server?

The result I want is this:

```
ID | 1 | 2 | 3 | ... | n
```

My attempt was the following:

```
DECLARE @Counter INT 
DECLARE @FCSTM INT = 36  -- Variable
DECLARE @Start INT = 0  -- Variable
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = Dateadd(mm, @Start, Dateadd(month, Datediff(month, 0, Getdate()), 0)) 
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = Dateadd(dd, -1, (DateAdd(mm, @FCSTM  + 1, @StartDate)))
SET @Counter=1
Tablex as
(SELECT DISTINCT ID,

WHILE ( @Counter <= @FCSTM)
BEGIN  
SUM(CASE WHEN (@Counter NOT BETWEEN Start AND End AND @FCSTM >= @Counter) THEN 0 END) as [@Counter],
SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
END

FROM Table123
GROUP BY ID)
```

Edit: Fleshed out the variables. The intention here is to dynamically have the query populate the SELECT statement with n number of columns, which are months. n here being @FCSTM - so if @FCSTM = 36 there will be 36 columns plus the ID col.

I was hoping for a FOR loop à la python eg.:

```
    @Counter = 1
    FOR i in range(0,@FCSTM):
        SUM(CASE WHEN (@Counter NOT BETWEEN Start AND End AND @FCSTM >= @Counter)
        @Counter = @Counter + 1
```

Which would give me:

```
(select distinct ID,


    SUM(CASE WHEN (0 NOT BETWEEN Start AND End AND @FCSTM >= 0) THEN 0 END) as [0],
    SUM(CASE WHEN (1 NOT BETWEEN Start AND End AND @FCSTM >= 1) THEN 0 END) as [1],
    SUM(CASE WHEN (2 NOT BETWEEN Start AND End AND @FCSTM >= 2) THEN 0 END) as [2],
...
SUM(CASE WHEN (36 NOT BETWEEN Start AND End AND @FCSTM >= 36) THEN 0 END) as [36]

from Table123
group by ID)
```

Comment: Not sure I fully understand what you're after here. Sample data and expected results will likely help.

Comment: @Larnu I hope my edit is clearer. I want something similar to what Atk posted below, but I don't want it as a stored procedure which has to be exectued as I want the output to go into and be used in a much larger query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by using dynamic sql.

```
create table Table123
(
ID int
)
```

Logic

```
DECLARE @Counter INT 
DECLARE @FCSTM INT
DECLARE @Start DATE
DECLARE @End DATE,@StrQuery varchar(max)
SET @Counter=0

set @StrQuery='select distinct ID,'

WHILE ( @Counter <= 40)
BEGIN  
set @StrQuery=@StrQuery+'null as '+ QUOTENAME(@Counter)+','
SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
END

set @StrQuery=SUBSTRING(@StrQuery,1,LEN(@StrQuery)-1)+' FROM Table123 Group by id'

exec (@StrQuery)
```

Output query

```
select distinct ID,null as [0],null as [1],null as [2],null as [3],null as [4],null as [5],null as [6],null as [7],null as [8],null as [9],null as [10],
null as [11],null as [12],null as [13],null as [14],null as [15],null as [16],null as [17],null as [18],null as [19],null as [20],null as [21],null as [22],
null as [23],null as [24],null as [25],null as [26],null as [27],null as [28],null as [29],null as [30],null as [31],null as [32],null as [33],null as [34],
null as [35],null as [36],null as [37],null as [38],null as [39],null as [40] FROM Table123 Group by id
```

Comment: Not really sure if this is what they want or not but you should look into tally tables. A loop here is not the best way of building this. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-numbers-or-tally-table-what-it-is-and-how-it-replaces-a-loop-1

Comment: Thanks! This is very useful and I am able to create the above statement in a seperate query, but the above is part of a much larger query, which has a second instance where I'd need a similar loop system, hence I had "Tablex as" and had the statement in (). So my followup is, how can I call @StrQuery without executing it?

Comment: @at8865 StrQuery contains the dynamic query, it must be executed to get the results and if you want to use the result somewhere else, insert the results in a temp table or a table variable.